# What the meaning of this index in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave

```
data = reshape(1:21504,[256,4,21]);
data(:,5:4:end)
```

I test some indexes, such as:

```
data(:,5:4:end) ~= data(:,5:4:end,1)
data(:,5:4:end) ~= data(:,1,5:4:end)
```

So what is the meaning of `data(:,5:4:end)`?

I test some other indexes, such as:

```
data(1,1) == data(1,1,1)
data(1,1:3) == data(1,1:3,1)
```

And find some strange behavior ,such as `data(1,1:10,1)` returns error but `data(1,1:10)` is ok.

So What's happening here?
How can I understand this mechanism?

Comment: there are some examples in the [MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> size(data)
ans =
256     4    21
```

`data(1,1:10,1)` selects column 1-10 from first row (all three dimensions are explicitly set), but there are only 4 columns. Therefore the error.

`data(1,1:10)`, on the other hand, uses Linear indexing, which interpretes dimensions 2 and 3 as one long strung of values and selects its first 10 values.

## Linear Indexing

```
What does this expression A(14) do?

When you index into the matrix A using only one subscript, MATLAB treats A as if its elements were strung out in a long column vector, by going down the columns consecutively, as in:

          16
           5
           9
         ...
           8
          12
           1

The expression A(14) simply extracts the 14th element of the implicit column vector. Indexing into a matrix with a single subscript in this way is often called linear indexing.

Here are the elements of the matrix A along with their linear indices:
matrix_with_linear_indices.gif

The linear index of each element is shown in the upper left.

From the diagram you can see that A(14) is the same as A(2,4).

The single subscript can be a vector containing more than one linear index, as in:

  A([6 12 15])
  ans =
      11   15   12

Consider again the problem of extracting just the (2,1), (3,2), and (4,4) elements of A. You can use linear indexing to extract those elements:

  A([2 7 16])
  ans =
      5   7   1

That's easy to see for this example, but how do you compute linear indices in general? MATLAB provides a function called sub2ind that converts from row and column subscripts to linear indices. You can use it to extract the desired elements this way:

  idx = sub2ind(size(A), [2 3 4], [1 2 4])
  ans =
      2   7   16
  A(idx)
  ans =
      5   7   1
```

(Copied from http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 1):

`data(:, 5:4:end)` will access all elements in the first dimension of `data` and starting from index 5 every 4th index until the last index in the second dimension of `data`. The syntax for this indexing technique can be explained like this:

```
data(startIndex:step:endIndex)
```

If `data` has more dimensions than you used for indexing, this will assume `:` for every dimension after that.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up my question:

```
data=reshape(1:24,2,3,4)
```

> data(:,:,1) =
>
> ```
>  1     3     5
>  2     4     6
> ```
>
> data(:,:,2) =
>
> ```
>  7     9    11
>  8    10    12
> ```
>
> data(:,:,3) =
>
> ```
> 13    15    17
> 14    16    18
> ```
>
> data(:,:,4) =
>
> ```
> 19    21    23
> 20    22    24
> ```

Using this example you can know what Matlab doing:

> data(:,1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1
>  2
> ```
>
> data(:,12)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 23
> 24
> ```
>
> data(:,[1,12])
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1    23
>  2    24
> ```
>
> data(:,5:4:end)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  9    17
> 10    18
> ```

If you use `data(:,13)`,it throws an error.